# typescript Object types are compared structurally

Tags: typescript

Per [Structural Subtyping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1.4)

> Object types are compared structurally. For example, in the code
> fragment below, class 'CPoint' matches interface 'Point' because
> 'CPoint' has all of the required members of 'Point'. A class may
> optionally declare that it implements an interface, so that the
> compiler will check the declaration for structural compatibility. The
> example also illustrates that an object type can match the type
> inferred from an object literal, as long as the object literal
> supplies all of the required members.

```
 interface Point {  
     x: number;  
     y: number;   }
 
 function getX(p: Point) {  
     return p.x;   }
 
 class CPoint {  
     x: number;  
     y: number;  
     constructor(x: number,  y: number) {  
         this.x = x;  
         this.y = y;  
     }   }
 
 getX(new CPoint(0, 0));  // Ok, fields match
 
 getX({ x: 0, y: 0, color: "red" });  // Extra fields Ok
 
 getX({ x: 0 });  // Error: supplied parameter does not match
```

In their example `CPoint` is considered of type `Point`, since it is of type `Point` I can pass it anywhere I can a `Point`. If `Point` stated that all implementors had method `Foo(x:string)`, `CPoint` wouldn't have that method. Thus anyone accepting a `Point` and expecting to use `Foo` would blow up if `CPoint` was passed into it.

**My question is, am I interpreting this wrong, if not why is this considered a good enough to put into the language specs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If Point stated that all implementors had method Foo(x:string), CPoint wouldn't have that method. Thus anyone accepting a Point and expecting to use Foo would blow up if CPoint was passed into it.

If you did this, you would get a compile-time error that `CPoint` lacked the `Foo` method. I recommend trying it on the TypeScript Playground.

Answer (score 1):

The type definitions/interfaces one creates are just a compile-time thing and in my opinion, the structural subtyping is a great feature.

If you extend the `Point` interface with an additional method `Foo(x: string)`, you tell the compiler that every object that wants to be a `Point` now also needs this method. In my opinion, this is exactly what you want to have because you can spot all places where you are passing objects that are lacking these additional properties.

Before adding such a method to an interface, it's probably better to ask yourself, if every object that has the characteristics of a `Point` really needs this method. In my experience it is often better to introduce some more interfaces, e.g. `Fooable` and using this where you need an object that needs to have the `Foo` method.

If you have a method that really needs objects having both characteristics, (x,y) and Foo, you can do something like this:

```
function myMethodRequiringASpecialObject(x: Point & Fooable) {}
```

This is called "intersection types". See more here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html